# Django rest framework jwt token permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, token

Now I made some API with Django rest-framework. And I used JWT for token authentication.
At this moment, I have some questions about token permission.
How can I detect token permission in Django?

For example, There is `user A` and `user B`.
When `user A` wrote article "test", article "test" can only be edited or deleted by `user A`.
But how can I detect permission about article "test"?

The token will be changed every time when user login. So detect by token is not the correct way.

I searching Google few hours, if there is any solution about this. Is there any way to determine user permission by token?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JWT tokens is used for authentification. So, once the user provided a valid token then he can login in your app. At this point you can retrieve the user instance and you can mange who can edit, delete or even add new posts.

Comment: See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Use)

Answer (score 0):

JWT authentication allows you to identify the user who have previously signed up to your Django app, thanks to the token attached to every request they send to your server.
Then, a permission (that you define and shape as you wish) allows you to let or not let user access / edit a given resource / page.
More practically, what you want to achieve can be set up as follows (assuming you use class based views):

```
class MyApiEndpoint(ApiView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
```

where:

- *JSONWebTokenAuthentication* is the authentication class provided by *djangorestframework-jwt*.
- *IsOwner* is a Permission class you need to write to check if the current user is owner of the resource hosted by the given view / API endpoint. ([More on this here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples)).

Comment: How can I implement this in simple-JWT library? I have deployed a Django application using Apache but I am getting the same answer as OP above.